# CSS for title onHover not working

Tags: html, css

I have a page which has some data in form of tables

Currently, for one of the columns(which is a link) I need to display a text on hover and was able to do it successfully by giving the title in the  tag. Now , I tried applying css to the text on hover and following is the snippet

CSS

```
a.changes:hover {text-decoration: none; }
a.changes p {position: absolute; left: -9999px;border-style:solid; border-color:black; border-width:1px;}
a.changes:hover p {left: 5%; background: #ffffff; size:1px;}
```

and in the html, I removed the title from the a tag and gave it in

inside  tag

```
<a href='#' class='changes' onclick='AAA'><font color=blue>XYZ</font><p style='width:100px;'>TextToBeDisplayedOnHover</p></a>";
```

The above snippet works fine on the current display. But when I scroll down the page and then try to display to text on hover by selecting the last element, then the title is not getting displayed at well. My guess the text on hover has gone beyond the display page vertically.

Someone please help me in this.  I need this hover to work for all the rows in the table in the current page as well as the next pages and not just the current display alone as happens in my case

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The html line is   -   <a href='#' class='changes' onclick='AAA'><font color=blue>XYZ</font><p style='width:100px;'>TextToBeDisplayedOnHover</p></a>";

Comment: Its hard to understand what exactly "fails". Could you make a screenshot or somethink like that. 
P.S. Use `display:none` instead of `left:-9999px` and `display: block` in hover-state

Comment: Try reproducing the bug in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) - there is not much we can do to help otherwise as it isn't clear what the problem is: http://jsfiddle.net/mcNxf/

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your problem but you have 100 pixels wide container so the "TextToBeDisplayedOnHover" doesn't fit into the container. You could try this (or widen the container):

```
a.changes:hover p {left: 5%; background: #ffffff; size:1px;width:100px;overflow:scroll;}
```

Lose the inline styles in the hovering ´p´. (You're using CSS already.)

```
<a href='#' class='changes' onclick='AAA'>XYZ<p>TextToBeDisplayedOnHover</p></a>
```

If you use spaces in the hovering text ("Text To Be Displayed On Hover") you'll be less likely to run out of space.

If blue isn't the the default font color, add this to your styles:

```
a {color:blue;}
```